# Python Numbers Guessing Game

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm a beginner programmer learning Python (using version 2.7.4) and I've made this number guessing game. Here's my code so far for it:

```
import random
name = raw_input("Hi there! What\'s your name?\n")
print "Well, " + name + ", I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100"
number = random.randint(1,100)
guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess:\n"))


count = 1

while guess != number:    
    if guess < number:
        print "Sorry, your guess is too low."                 
    if guess > number:
        print "Sorry, your guess is too high."
    count += 1
    guess = int(raw_input("Take another guess\n"))

print "Good job, %s! You guessed my number in %d guesses!" % (name ,count)
```

1. How do I alert the player of a guess that they've already previously guessed before?
2. How do I make sure that the player can only input numbers as their guess? I'm stumped. 
   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, use a [*set*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to track the previous input values:

```
seen = set()
while guess != number:    
    if guess < number:
        print "Sorry, your guess is too low."                 
    if guess > number:
        print "Sorry, your guess is too high."
    count += 1
    while True:
        guess = int(raw_input("Take another guess\n"))
        if guess in seen:
            print "Oops, you have guess than one before"
            continue
        else:
            seen.add(guess)
            break
```

For the second question, you could use the [*isinstance()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#isinstance) function, but there isn't much of a need.  The [*int()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#int) function will check the input for you and will raise an exception if you did not get an integer input.  If you would like, you could catch that exception and add a nice error message:

```
    try:
        guess = int(raw_input("Take another guess\n"))
    except ValueError:
        print "Sorry, I expected an integer"
```

Comment: Hmm, I get an error message:
    seen.add(guess)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: @Patricia Thats strange, the ``seen`` variable is a ``set`` not a ``dict``. Could you update your question with the new code you have?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for question one make a list:

```
while run:
    geusslist = []
    number = raw_input("Make A Geuss")
    geusslist.extend((number))

if print_nums:
    print "You Have Guessed:"
    print geusslist
```

If this code is ran and the player guesses 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 it should return

```
>>> You Have Geussed:
>>> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

As for question two i think 'Raymond Hettinger' answered that above ^ very well.